# Combining 2 sections according to the reviewer’s comment

Tags: publications, paper-submission, peer-review

I get review comments for my manuscript. Reviewer suggested combine G section with B section as one section. So I combined as he/she suggested. Now I am preparing REPLY to reviewer’s comments. My question is that should I put my whole combined section to REPLY file and highlight the combined G section’s texts? Or Is this okay if I reply like this “According to your suggestion, we combined G section with B section as one section”?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"The material from sections B and G of the previous version have been incorporated into the new Section H of this version".

That should be plenty. Just point to the place where the material now sits as suggested above.